# MiniProfiler ProfilingActionFilter & ProfilingViewEngine both not found

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

After upgrading from MiniProfiler v2 to v3 the ProfilingActionFilter & ProfilingViewEngine appear to be missing?

I've googled and even checked the assembly for something similar, but there is nothing that stands out as it's replacement?

Am I missing something?

Below is my `Using` and my section of code try to implement this.

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;



GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());

ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(razorEngine));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please make sure that in addition to the main MiniProfiler assembly, you have also installed the [MiniProfiler.MVC4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.Mvc4/) nuget. This assembly (StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc) includes the [`ProfilingActionFilter`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc/ProfilingActionFilter.cs) and [`ProfilingViewEngine`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc/ProfilingViewEngine.cs) classes, both in the `StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc` namespace.

You can [see these in action](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/b3f2f2118225c4440eb14a089643776eb9d5c410/Sample.Mvc/Global.asax.cs#L60) in the Sample.Mvc project.